# What is out keyword in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am not able to understand and I couldn't find the meaning of **out** keyword in kotlin.

You can check example here:

```
List<out T>
```

If any one can explain the meaning of this. It would be really appreciated.

Comment: Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Answer (score 100, accepted):

With this signature:

```
List<out T>
```

you can do this:

```
val doubleList: List<Double> = listOf(1.0, 2.0)
val numberList: List<Number> = doubleList
```

which means **T** is **covariant**:

> when a type parameter **T** of a class **C** is declared **out**, **C<Base>** can safely be a **supertype** of **C<Derived>**.

This is contrast with **in**, e.g.

```
Comparable<in T>
```

you can do this:

```
fun foo(numberComparable: Comparable<Number>) {
  val doubleComparable: Comparable<Double> = numberComparable
  // ...
}
```

which means **T** is **contravariant**:

> when a type parameter **T** of a class **C** is declared **in**, **C<Derived>** can safely be a **supertype** of **C<Base>**.

Another way to remember it:

> Consumer **in**, Producer **out**.

see [Kotlin Generics Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

**-----------------updated on 4 Jan 2019-----------------**

For the "**Consumer in, Producer out**", we only read from Producer - call method to get result of type T; and only write to Consumer - call method by passing in parameter of type T.

In the example for `List<out T>`, it is obvious that we can do this:

```
val n1: Number = numberList[0]
val n2: Number = doubleList[0]
```

So it is safe to provide `List<Double>` when `List<Number>` is expected, hence `List<Number>` is super type of `List<Double>`, but not vice versa.

In the example for `Comparable<in T>`:

```
val double: Double = 1.0
doubleComparable.compareTo(double)
numberComparable.compareTo(double)
```

So it is safe to provide `Comparable<Number>` when `Comparable<Double>` is expected, hence `Comparable<Double>` is super type of `Comparable<Number>`, but not vice versa.

Comment: I think the most important point for one seeing  `List<out T>` declaration is that `out` makes it immutable (compared to mutable collections, which do not have out). It may help to mention and emphasize that in the answer. Implicit casting is a consequence of this rather than main point (since one cannot write to List<Number>, safe to have it as a reference to List<Double>).

Comment: @minsk The `out` part isn't what makes `List` immutable though. You can easily make your own `List<out T>` interface that has a `clear()` method since it wouldn't require any arguments.

Comment: this is one of those topics that you probably want get until you really need it somewhere in your code.

Comment: This is super confusing. What I like to remember is the rule PECS - producer extends, consumer super. In Kotlin `out` maps to the producer, `in` to the consumer.

Comment: The example is very clear and correct. I think that `Collection<out E>` as defined in Kotlin library is extremely confusing, though. In fact everyone could wonder why `Collection` can be a producer of `E` if it accepts `E` as input parameter as well (see `::contains(E)`).
The trick is `@UnsafeVariance` annotation. But nowhere this is mentioned, and you must go trouhgh the source code to get it and say.... "oooohhhh"!!!

Answer (score 263):

`List<out T>` in Kotlin is equivalent to `List<? extends T>` in Java.

`List<in T>` in Kotlin is equivalent to `List<? super T>` in Java

For example in Kotlin you can do things like

```kotlin
val value : List<Any> = listOf(1,2,3)
//since List signature is List<out T> in Kotlin
```

The reasoning is you can mark generic "out" if you returning it, but never receiving. And you can mark it "in" if you receive it, but never return.

Comment: There's no easier way to explain it than this. I immediately understood it as the `? extends T` and `? super T` is easier to understand than `out T` and `in T` IMO.

Comment: added reasoning. It's actually easier to see if you only returning it or receiving only, rather than learn what "? super T" means.

Comment: I actually got confused by the reasoning, which I already found in books and the documentation. 
I still don't know which context is meant by returning and receiving here - I have an Array<out String> as a parameter type (from varargs), so that goes INTO my function. 
I have understood co- and invariance in the past but always have to recap it tediously. This is one of the few features of Kotlin that I find consistently annoying - might change if I ever grasp it for good.

Answer (score 181):

The variance modifiers `out` and `in` allow us to make our generic types less restrictive and more reusable by allowing subtyping.

Let's understand this with the help of contrasting examples. We'll use examples of cases as containers of various weapons. Assume that we have the following type hierarchy:

```
open class Weapon
open class Rifle : Weapon()
class SniperRifle : Rifle()
```

---

### `out` produces `T` and *preserves* subtyping

When you declare a generic type with an `out` modifier, it's called *covariant*. A covariant is a *producer* of `T`, that means functions can return `T` but they can't take `T` as arguments:

```
class Case<out T> {
    private val contents = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun produce(): T = contents.last()         // Producer: OK
    fun consume(item: T) = contents.add(item)  // Consumer: Error
}
```

The `Case` declared with the `out` modifier produces `T` and its subtypes:

```
fun useProducer(case: Case<Rifle>) {
    // Produces Rifle and its subtypes
    val rifle = case.produce()
}
```

With the `out` modifier, the subtyping is *preserved*, so the `Case<SniperRifle>` is a subtype of `Case<Rifle>` when `SniperRifle` is a subtype of `Rifle`. As a result, the `useProducer()` function can be called with `Case<SniperRifle>` too:

```
useProducer(Case<SniperRifle>())               // OK
useProducer(Case<Rifle>())                     // OK
useProducer(Case<Weapon>())                    // Error
```

This is *less restrictive* and *more reusable* while producing but our class becomes *read only*.

---

### `in` consumes `T` and *reverses* subtyping

When you declare a generic type with an `in` modifier, it's called `contravariant`. A contravariant is a *consumer* of `T`, that means functions can take `T` as arguments but they can't return `T`:

```
class Case<in T> {
    private val contents = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun produce(): T = contents.last()         // Producer: Error
    fun consume(item: T) = contents.add(item)  // Consumer: OK
}
```

The `Case` declared with the `in` modifier consumes `T` and its subtypes:

```
fun useConsumer(case: Case<Rifle>) {
    // Consumes Rifle and its subtypes
    case.consume(SniperRifle())
}
```

With the `in` modifier, the subtyping is *reversed*, so now the `Case<Weapon>` is a subtype of `Case<Rifle>` when `Rifle` is a subtype of `Weapon`. As a result, the `useConsumer()` function can be called with `Case<Weapon>` too:

```
useConsumer(Case<SniperRifle>())               // Error          
useConsumer(Case<Rifle>())                     // OK
useConsumer(Case<Weapon>())                    // OK
```

This is *less restrictive* and *more reusable* while consuming but our class becomes *write only*.

---

### Invariant produces and consumes `T`, *disallows* subtyping

When you declare a generic type without any variance modifier, it's called *invariant*. An invariant is a producer as well as a consumer of `T`, that means functions can take `T` as arguments and can also return `T`:

```
class Case<T> {
    private val contents = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun produce(): T = contents.last()         // Producer: OK
    fun consume(item: T) = contents.add(item)  // Consumer: OK
}
```

The `Case` declared without `in` or `out` modifier produces and consumes `T` and its subtypes:

```
fun useProducerConsumer(case: Case<Rifle>) {
    // Produces Rifle and its subtypes
    case.produce()
    // Consumes Rifle and its subtypes
    case.consume(SniperRifle())
}
```

Without the `in` or `out` modifier, the subtyping is *disallowed*, so now neither `Case<Weapon>` nor `Case<SniperRifle>` is a subtype of `Case<Rifle>`. As a result, the `useProducerConsumer()` function can only be called with `Case<Rifle>`:

```
useProducerConsumer(Case<SniperRifle>())       // Error
useProducerConsumer(Case<Rifle>())             // OK
useProducerConsumer(Case<Weapon>())            // Error
```

This is *more restrictive* and *less reusable* while producing and consuming but we can *read and write*.

---

### Conclusion

The `List` in Kotlin is a producer only. Because it's declared using the `out` modifier: `List<out T>`. This means you cannot add elements to it as the `add(element: T)` is a consumer function. Whenever you want to be able to `get()` as well as `add()` elements, use the invariant version `MutableList<T>`.

That's it! Hopefully that helps understand the `in`s and `out`s of the variance!

Comment: This is one of the most lucid explanations out there (especially for a complex topic such as Generics). Kudos to you!

Comment: @Sdr, Thank you! I'm glad you found it useful!

Comment: very clear unlike the kotlin docs. thanks for this explanation!

Answer (score 31):

These answers explain **what** `out` does, but not **why** you need it, so let's pretend we didn't have `out` at all. Imagine three classes: Animal, Cat, Dog, and a function taking a list of `Animal`

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract fun speak()
}

class Dog: Animal() {
  fun fetch() {}
  override fun speak() { println("woof") }
}

class Cat: Animal() {
  fun scratch() {}
  override fun speak() { println("meow") }
}
```

Since a `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`, we want to use `List<Dog>` as a subtype of `List<Animal>` which means we want to be able to do this:

```
fun allSpeak(animals: List<Animal>) {
    animals.forEach { it.speak() }
}

fun main() {
  val dogs: List<Dog> = listOf(Dog(), Dog())
  allSpeak(dogs)

  val mixed: List<Animal> = listOf(Dog(), Cat())
  allSpeak(mixed)
}
```

And that's fine, the code will print `woof woof` for the dogs and `woof meow` for the mixed list.

**The problem** is when we have a mutable container. Since a `List<Animal>` can contain `Dog` and `Cat`, we can add either to a `MutableList<Animal>`

```
fun addCat(animals: MutableList<Animal>) {
   animals.add(Cat()) // uh oh, what if this is a list of Dogs?
}

fun main() {
  val dogs: MutableList<Dog> = mutableListOf(Dog(), Dog())
  addCat(dogs) // we just added a Cat to a list of Dogs!
  val d: Dog = dogs.last() // list of Dogs, so return type of .last() is Dog
                           // but this is actually a Cat
  d.fetch() // a Cat can't fetch, so what should happen here?
}
```

You can't safely consider `MutableList<Dog>` to be a subtype of `MutableList<Animal>` because you can do things to the latter (insert a cat) which you can't do to the former.

As a more extreme example:

```
val dogs: MutableList<Dog> = mutableListOf(Dog())
val anything: MutableList<Any> = dogs
// now I can add any type I want to the dogs list through the anything list
anything.add("hello world")
```

The problem only occurs when adding to the list, not reading from it. It is safe to use `List<Dog>` as `List<Animal>` because you can't append to `List`. This is what `out` tells us. `out` says "this is a type which I output, but I don't take it as new inputs which I consume"

Comment: @NaveenRao if you didn't have `out` then trying to call `allSpeak(mixed)` would fail to compile. You'd only be able call it with `List<Animal>`

Comment: @NaveenRao actually sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. `List` is declared as `List<out T>`. Are you asking for an answer about what safety `in` gives you?

Comment: Yeah i meant that as you gave examples of why there's need of `out`and `in`. Can you give same examples using `out`and `in`?

Comment: @NaveenRao in the real world, `List` does use `out`, so `allSpeak` works and is safe

Comment: this is a great explanation, but it seems to me that In and Out are here to correct a design issue in the program. with a good design of Class and inheritance, you should'nt face any situation where in and out are necessay. These notions don't exist in typescript for example or I didn't catch the point?

Comment: @Jerome they don't exist in typescript, and as a consequence [typescript's type system is less safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922930/1013719)

Answer (score 27):

Remember like this:

`in` is "for **in**put" - you wanna put(write) something into it (so it's a "consumer")

`out` is "for **out**put" - you wanna take(read) something out of it (so it's a "producer")

If you're from Java,

`<in T>` is for input, so it's like `<? super T>` (consumer)

`<out T>` is for output, so it's like `<? extends T>` (producer)

Answer (score 7):

**produce = output = out.**

```
interface Production<out T> {
    fun produce(): T
}
```

If your generic class only use the generic type as output of it’s function/s, then out is used

**consume = input = in.**

```
   interface Consumer<in T> {
    fun consume(item: T)
}
```

If your generic class only use the generic type as input of it’s function/s, then in is used

Please refer
https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/in-and-out-type-variant-of-kotlin-587e4fa2944c
for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

you can treat it as:

- in -> zoom in -> any classes/interfaces the T inherited from
- out ->
  zoom out -> any classes that inherited T

That simple.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to thie [manual of kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

> The Kotlin `List<out T>` type is an interface that provides read only
>   operations like size, get and so on. Like in Java, it inherits from
>   `Collection<T>` and that in turn inherits from `Iterable<T>`. Methods that
>   change the list are added by the `MutableList<T>` interface. This
>   pattern holds also for `Set<out T>/MutableSet<T>` and `Map<K, out`
>   `V>/MutableMap<K, V>`

And this,

> In Kotlin, there is a way to explain this sort of thing to the
>   compiler. This is called declaration-site variance: we can annotate
>   the type parameter T of Source to make sure that it is only returned
>   (produced) from members of `Source<T>`, and never consumed. To do this
>   we provide the out modifier:
>
> ```
> > abstract class Source<out T> {
> >     abstract fun nextT(): T }
> > 
> > fun demo(strs: Source<String>) {
> >     val objects: Source<Any> = strs // This is OK, since T is an out-parameter
> >     // ... }
> ```
>
> The general rule is: when a type parameter `T` of a class `C` is declared
>   out, it may occur only in out-position in the members of `C`, but in
>   return `C<Base>` can safely be a supertype of `C<Derived>`.
>
> In "clever words" they say that the class `C` is covariant in the
>   parameter `T`, or that `T` is a covariant type parameter. You can think of
>   C as being a producer of T's, and NOT a consumer of `T`'s.
>   The out modifier is called a variance annotation, and since it is
>   provided at the type parameter declaration site, we talk about
>   declaration-site variance. This is in contrast with Java's use-site
>   variance where wildcards in the type usages make the types covariant.

Answer (score 0):

A nice explanation from [Functional programming in Kotlin](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-kotlin):

Consider the following code:

```
sealed class List<out A>

object Nil : List<Nothing>()

data class Cons<out A>(val head: A, val tail: List<A>) : List<A>()
```

> In the declaration class List, the out in front of the type parameter A is a variance annotation signaling that A is a covariant or “positive” parameter of List. This means, for instance, that List is considered a subtype of List, assuming Dog is a subtype of Animal. (More generally, for all types X and Y, if X is a subtype of Y, then List is a subtype of List.) We could omit the out in front of A, which would make List invariant in that type parameter.
> But notice now Nil extends List. Nothing is a subtype of all types, which means in conjunction with the variance annotation, Nil can be considered a List, a List, and so on, exactly as we want.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s make it simple

Assume you have such a class structure:

```
class Burger: FastFood
open class FastFood: Food 
open class Food

***Invariants Generic Class*** 
class FixedGenericType<T> {
    fun returnData(): T {…}
    fun useData(param: T) {…}

var fixedGenericType: FixedGenericType<FastFood> = 
    FixedGenericType<FastFood>() ✅
    FixedGenericType<Food>() ❌
    FixedGenericType<Burger>() ❌

***Contravariant Generic Class*** 
class ConsumerGenericType<in T> {
    fun returnData(): T {…} ❌
    fun useData(param: T) {…}

var consumerGenericType: ConsumerGenericType<FastFood> = 
    ConsumerGenericType<FastFood>() ✅
    ConsumerGenericType<Food>() ✅
    ConsumerGenericType<Burger>() ❌

***Covariant Generic Class*** 
class ProducerGenericType<out T> {
    fun returnData(): T {…} 
    fun useData(param: T) {…} ❌

var producerGenericType: ProducerGenericType<FastFood> =
    ProducerGenericType<FastFood>() ✅
    ProducerGenericType<Food>() ❌
    ProducerGenericType<Burger>() ✅
```