# Why does this arrow function in an interface not compile?

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-typings

What is the difference between ***Arrow Functions*** and ***Regular Functions*** in implementing Interfaces, so that code **A** causes compile-time error and code **B** compiles successfully.

Note: in `tsconfig.json` all strict type-checking options are enabled, including `strictFunctionTypes`, BTW it supposed that by enabling `strict` all strict type-checking options get enabled.

Code **A** that causes compile time error

```
interface SomeInterface {
    someFunction: (par1: string | undefined) => string;
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    someFunction(par1: string): string    //invalid function signature
    {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
}
```

And, Code **B** that compiles successfully.

```
interface SomeInterface {
    someFunction(par1: string | undefined): string;
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    someFunction(par1: string): string    //invalid function signature
    {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhcgM5YQBiAriAmMOiAFzIAUADnFACMXKmCigA5sgA%20yJgBMIMUBHkBKZAF4AfNTGSA3KQC%20pUggA2cKlTS0AwlZvJgmXhYjZwtjNjyRYRBQySmpaRmZWdj4BYT1xEAk1EX1E0IB6dNAANzgLYHlkGCYWNhBqYAkQODAGKAhyShDQyjAACyh0AHdkEAgegFEoTqhuAHIAWQh29EKQdDAXNw8vSHkAOjG1I1DTU1JQAMIUX1x8QKQAJhJGihpsCNLo-iEUhKlZBSUVdTfDEzMlmsPgcTio11c7k8EG8dj852O12ad3CJSiIBir3ikmS2LSlEyOTyBSKaLKFSqNTqDVCyJa7U6PT6g2G6FGACIpjM5gsllDVqp1uztrdkHsgA)

Comment: Typescript is fast becoming a bizarre language. I wish they'd chose to either have proper OO structures or not. There's a lot of weird half way houses.

Comment: Every once in a while when this sort of soundness topic comes up, and I find myself reading through [ms/TS#9825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825) during the research for my answer.  I think there should be a TypeScript Unsoundness Support Group where people get together and help each other process their feelings about how TypeScript isn't actually type safe. I'm not even completely joking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) enabled, *function types*' parameters are checked [contravariantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_parameter_type), as required to maintain type safety:

```
class SomeClass implements SomeInterface { // error here
    someFunction(par1: string): string  
    {
        return par1.toUpperCase();
    }
}

const i: SomeInterface = new SomeClass(); // error here
i.someFunction(undefined); // runtime error here, par1 is undefined
```

But, as mentioned in the documentation:

> During development of this feature, we discovered a large number of inherently unsafe class hierarchies, including some in the DOM. Because of this, the setting only applies to functions written in *function* syntax, not to those in *method* syntax.

---

So *method types*' parameters are still checked [bivariantly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), meaning both contavariantly and [covariantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_parameter_type), in order to support some common patterns (although perhaps [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) or [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) would be a better way to do it for some of these cases).  The big example is `Array<T>`, where people [apparently like their covariant arrays](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant):

```
interface Animal { species: string }
interface Dog extends Animal { bark(): void };
const scooby: Dog = { species: "dog", bark() { console.log("ROOBY ROO or whatevz") } };
const snoopy: Dog = { species: "dog", bark() { console.log("...") } };
function processAnimals(arr: Animal[]) {
    console.log("I got " + arr.map(x => x.species).join(", ") + ".")
};
const dogs = [scooby, snoopy];
processAnimals(dogs); // okay
```

This is ergonomic and common, but technically the compiler should reject `dogs` because `Dog[]` would not be a valid `Animal[]` (indeed, methods like `push()` will do bad things like push a `Cat` into a `Dog[]` under the hood).  But if you go down this route you find out that TypeScript is unsound all over the place in exactly this way, even without function parameters, because property writes are also like this.  See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922930/2887218) for more elaboration.

---

And *that* means your `SomeClass2` produces no error since `SomeInterface2` uses method syntax:

```
class SomeClass2 implements SomeInterface2 { // no error
    someFunction(par1: string): string {
        return par1.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Of course this has exactly the same soundness problem as before:

```
const i2: SomeInterface2 = new SomeClass2(); // no error
i2.someFunction(undefined); // runtime error, par1 is undefined
```

But that's just the way it is.  Methods are less safe than functions by design, for convenience.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhcgM5YQBiAriAmMOiAFzIAUADnFACMXKmCigA5sgA+yJgBMIMUBHkBKZAF4AfNTGSA3KQC+pUggA2cKlTS0AwlZvJgmXhYjZwtjNjyRYRBQySmpaRmZWdj4BYT1xEAk1EX1E0IB6dNAANzgLYHlkGCYWNhBqYAkQODAGKAhyShDQynraqHL+IQA6MHQAVV5eaHtrCG41I1DTU3N2URcuX1x8QKJNZBAIAHc7bEdrKgmjMQBPEkaKYG6abAjS6IUlFXUjY2QEGoQACx4IDWaFAQ83QHm6FnQEm4-wMyEyyC6ghctieyi28hMZlAAUIKAAgiBXHkSNRhghgBAqCkElJTNiCEFkAARSHICAAD0gIHktgJRIsJIARgIANYTLjZdAFZDGIzAkALKjA9CC05cFlSDbEUkQcmUrgAInkkINABpkMKoGKAR8QWCIVCDQAlADyLoAQgBNZCul3IdBQZDbb41CDZABeBo071lcwVYGoIHQ6F4auZrK1Or1VOQRpN5st1pJ8po9sh3AN3SrUZlMqMxUiZQRUHQSBsfMweSOAigXA7eQA2gBdAGXW0K0EQcHlg04ZASdAJg3IADUyB73U7vG47K0unZNzJFKoam6ACspSAK+aa2vK1GTHL5gnjRJbBsB0rk6rzVQkynTiHIxeBbNsqH7CwjlfE9YXhdARTgU4sVWXE9hWHEggAJguUJbnoEooivRFqUkGQ5G5Z50WSeJDExcwnB8BwGOw1x3E8CBvDQ-wGSQbDATCO4CLKGIhBIxJqNEGkcJaCg2jqTpYl6AYhhGMZjjHGYzDjBZgEwpZaG4tYIGwjYtl2ZYDhsTDjmQUgzmkq5MJucIhMeCi0VUSYTA+L5fmhUdQhLSdpyhGE4XSBFYmRcjFA8jFjCAA)

Comment: Great answer. The fact that this is so complex says a lot...

Comment: @Liam Since jcalz beat me with a much more detailed answer :), I'll just link my talk on variance here maybe you'll find it useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EInunOVRsUU

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Seriously impressive explanations. Thanks so much. I left a comment on the video with a question if you have some time to check it