# TypeScript this in interface should reference itself and children, not only itself

Tags: typescript

There is the example:

```
interface A {
    method: (itself: this) => string;
}

interface B extends A {
    additionalProperty: boolean;
}

type Extend<T extends A> = A & { extension: number };

type ExtendedA = Extend<A>

type ExtendedB = Extend<B>
```

[The sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=13&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4CgCQBbCMACwHsATALmQApgwBnCAGxiuOHoEpkBeAPmT0wUUAHMA3FgC+WLKEixEKAELIIAD0ggy9NJlxwyZOsBIg4TAApQSAB2hgAnlQBGJEkwhwQkmVif2yACimhDaADwAKmqh2rqoAjx6AGSYMVr0piBUIACueC7QyFKS-o6BIVpkEGToSZVhZOEJsgEoDdo1qvWxTcp8QA).

When I try to extend `B` TypeScript writes:

> Type 'B' does not satisfy the constraint 'A'.
> Types of property 'method' are incompatible.
> Type '(itself: B) => string' is not assignable to type '(itself: A) => string'.
> Types of parameters 'itself' and 'itself' are incompatible.
> Property 'additionalProperty' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.(2344)
> input.tsx(6, 2): 'additionalProperty' is declared here.

But `B` extends `A`. They should be compatible.

**UPDATE #1:**

I can't explain this, but [it seems that if I replace interfaces by classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQBIAtgUwC4AsD2AJgBQCWWEGIAZgFzS4kQCUiqKATtgK7sB20AciwYIWAQG5UAXyQzQkGACFoGAB7DeBGPGQowBAmRJ5eYEAAV2eAA4Z2WAJ7QAvPXZcMkmUke3oAUXUMTQAeABUVIM1tAD4XaAiAMkRIjQhjXjpeLjQAIztoKUkfBz9AjQIMAnhXcuCCENgYpBKyqMqCZVr2kMUYoA) typing works perfect.

**UPDATE #2:**

Well, it works only with class methods, but it doesn't work, for example, arrow functions. Still strange.

**UPDATE #3**

If the interface is defined in the following way it doesn't work:

```
interface A {
    method: (itself: this) => string;
}
```

But if it's defined in the following way it does work:

```
interface A {
    method(itself: this): string;
}
```

It has no sense at all. But looking for the reason of this behavior I found [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70277549). It gave me a clue to reasons of this difference.

There was mentioned the TypeScript option [`strictFunctionTypes`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/blob/v2/packages//tsconfig-reference/copy/en/options/strictFunctionTypes.md).

> When enabled, this flag causes functions parameters to be checked more correctly.

> During development of this feature, we discovered a large number of inherently unsafe class hierarchies, including some in the DOM. Because of this, the setting only applies to functions written in function syntax, not to those in method syntax

It explains the reason of that strange difference in behavior. I can just turn off this option, but it feels like a workaround.

I still need another solution.

**UPDATE #4**

I assume this error is designated to prevent such unsafe assignments:

```
const a: A = {
    method(b: B) {
        return `${b.toString()} / ${b.additionalProperty}`;
    }
}
```

But such type of errors are not specific for my case.

**UPDATE #5**

I've found another workaround

```
type Method<T extends (...args: any) => any> = {
    f(...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;
}['f'];
```

```
interface A {
    method: Method<(itself: this) => string>;
}

interface B extends A {
    additionalProperty: boolean;
}

type Extend<T extends A> = T & { extension: number };

type ExtendedA = Extend<A>

type ExtendedB = Extend<B>
```

[Check it yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAPAFShAHsCAdigM5QAUAdFQIYBOA5sQFxTUEgCUUAvAHyvt+3KAG8AUAEgAZpRoNmUAAp1qAW3gRaxTLw4sASvACutAhnAQdAbjEBfANoByKY4C6NsQEsC+WlOoAxtAAgqKS6oioLHCR6GSewMQQADZSLIiexFx8UMTAtN70vDa2Yl4+mv5BUABC2HiEJFCh4hLUKCgJnkgE1MmKtEiQtKAsAEZISMkQbCVloJBQAKINRJj1+ESkwUJQWABkohuExN0ELARGqmOaULYeC9ArmygQKKHCz41oO-MWy6tXig6p9AWgarwgA). It's better than disabling of `strictFunctionTypes`, but it's still workaround.

Comment: But the this parameter is not. In A it's simply A but in B it's B, not A.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass it and preserve typing?

Comment: I think your fifth update is actually more verbose than using plain method syntax.

Comment: It is. But it gives me the possibility to not limit myself by functions: `property: string | Method<(something: this) => string>`. It's impossible with plain method syntax.

Comment: Ah yeah good point!

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyowrd is dependent on the context where it is being defined.
When it is defined in `interface A` it references `A`, and in `interface B` it references `B`

Hence they both become incompatible when checking the `extends` constraint.

**Solution 1 :**

So either we can explicitly define them separately or just add a union of them `A | B`

```
interface A {
    method: (itself: A | B) => string;
}

interface B extends A {
    additionalProperty: boolean;
}

type Extend<T extends A> = T & { extension: number };

type ExtendedA = Extend<A>

type ExtendedB = Extend<B>
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4CgCQBbCMACwHsATALmQApgwBnCAGxivQB9kAhASmQF4AfMnpgooAOYBuLAF8sWUJFiIUXZBAAekEGXppMuOGTJ1gJEHCYAFKCQAO0MAE8qAIxIkmEOCBnysF0dkAFFtCF0AHgAVDXDdfVRhfmRYgDJMOJ16cxAqEABXPDdoZFkZQOdgsJ0yCDJ0FJqIskikhSCUZt169Sb41q5BLCA)

**Solution 2 :**

We can make `method<T> (): void` a generic function so that the `context-related` ambiguity for `this` is solved.

```
interface A {
    method: <T> (itself: T) => void;
}

interface B extends A {
    additionalProperty: boolean;
}

type Extend<T extends A> = T & { extension: number };

type ExtendedA = Extend<A>

type ExtendedB = Extend<B>

const b: B = {
    method<B>() {
        console.log(this.additionalProperty) 
    },
    additionalProperty: true
}
```

[Code Playground Solution 2](https://tsplay.dev/N7O94N)

Comment: I've tried it before. This approach has the disadvantage. There are the problems with the definition of the method type. It's only argument should have the type `B`, but it has the type `A | B` and it leads to headache (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4CgCQBbCMACwHsATALmQApgwBnCAGxivQB9kAhASmQF4AfMgBuJYGQDcWAL5YsoSLEQouyCAA9IIMvTSZccMmTrASIOEwAKUEgAdoYAJ5UARiRJMIcENLlZnB2QAUS0IHQAeABV1MJ09VGF+ZBiAMkxY7XozECoQAFc8V2hkGWkApyDQ7TIIMnRk6vCyCMT5QJQmnTq1RriWrkF5BHN6MGRXKl6DfEJSMmpXPmwcHBGQek8IADomEgBzRe2jEzAcyxt7Ryc+XBkAGkNjU3ML2wcoZyowKHyIWSwQA)

Comment: @nitrovatter What if we solve the problem, by making method Generics `method<T>` so that there will be no context-related ambiguity?
[Code Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7O94N)
I will update my answer if it satisfies your requirement

Comment: It's pretty annoying to define <B> for each of generic functions. Also, you are able to set any possible type here. I've tried to solve it the following way, but get the strange error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4CgCQBbCMACwHsATALmQB4AVZCAD0hDIGc1kBeZY4NgHzIAFMDBsIAGxhVaASm5CAbiWBkA3FgC+WLKEixEKAEINmEVh3TYccMmTHASIOJIAKUEgAdoYAJ5UAEYkJJIQcCCaOlgIzmxgyIFUpjw2BMTkouJSMAo2OGIS0gB0dg5gTi7unj5Q-rhaADS4ZY7Orh7evgG8UACuENq6-j7IAKLmrHRmLOxoQjz0AGSYMxZslVQgfXiB0MhamlgjKBOzEGToPGcWZNSoAsN+ozesFynjk3fGj0A

Comment: Why are you trying to type `itself`, you don't need it actually for your purpose
Just use `this` keyword.
 
`const b: B = {  method() { this.additionalProperty }, additionalProperty: true }`

Comment: This functions can be stored and used separately. Sometimes `this` won't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a type constraint on the method definition of your `A` interface?

```js
interface A {
  method: <T extends this> (itself: T) => string;
}
```

---

Could you use a class instead?

```js
abstract class A  {
    abstract method(itself: { [field in keyof this]: this[field] }): string;
}

interface B extends A {
    additionalProperty: boolean;
}

type Extend<T extends A> = T & { extension: number };

type ExtendedA = Extend<A>

type ExtendedB = Extend<B>

const t: ExtendedB = {
    additionalProperty: true,
    extension: 1,
    method(obj) {
        return obj.additionalProperty.toString();
    }
}
```

[See it in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAggghBvAUAJCiQzwIC2AphABYD2AJgBQCWEYVyAZgFx4IA2t1ZdGCVgDsEAayoBPetwR1WYALr9VYYaOSN1CAL4BKfqSkBzANz4j+fFIhUo3OFQQAhBFQAezyUYMbAJiRkZ2VnpJYGQABSh6AAcXCHl+EHp6ZCpgSVt7fDSUhABRfypAgB4AFR8KwOCAPgQAXgQ6gDIBPwCwKMl+SQBXChAXY1si+RLygMYqRmx2ucrGKswmh2KPVcDF7xWG9c8t-FhoyBV+PYXGQ7wiYHDI6NiE5NT0lShhqgAaIi9Sr9aL8ACMgMI1DoTGY9BAACsTI9CIQoDRhlBpAjEQA6Z4RCADd6JFJQNJ4iD0ADK0CszBMtkI9iMQA)

Comment: Interesting idea. But it works strange:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4CgCQBbCMACwHsATALmQB4AVZCAD0hDIGdljg2A+ZACmBg2EADYwqtAJTIAvHzZgooAOYBuLAF8sWUJFiIUAIQbMIrDumw44ZMkOAkQcUQAUoJAA7QwATyoARiQkohBwIBraWH7eyACiZqx0pizsaHyyyPQAZJgp5myOIFQgAK54AdDImhrRvrEJqRBk6JmN5mTUqDw6MSjtrM0mbYmdRj1YCE6KnFQDZENymLi29mBFLu5ePv6cUKUQADS4TCyFTlQAjMf4hKRk-CQBAFYy1jhQhKVQIMhPzwA6VYOJybDzeKB+AFgEgAZSUqn4Ug0OG0miAA

Comment: Could you use a class instead of an interface?

Comment: I can, but not in an every situation. I've explain the details in my answer above with hack solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72222665/10118104

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

This problem occurred only if `strictFunctionTypes` flag is on (that's default in the strict mode, so it's common case). Under this flag function type parameter positions are checked *contravariantly* instead of *bivariantly*.

In this case:
`(arg: B) => void` is not assignable to `(arg: A) => void` even if `B extends A`,

Solutions:

a) Use methods instead of properties if it's possible. The methods type parameter positions are checked bivariantly.

b) Use bivariance hack to force TypeScript checks type parameter positions bivariantly.

```
type Bivariant<T extends (...args: any) => any> = {
    f(...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;
}['f'];
```

```
let callback: Bivariant<(event: E) => void>
```

c) Disable `strictFunctionTypes` flag. But it won't help the other users that will use your code, so it's barely solution.

**Root of the problem.**

Again, this problem occurred only if `strictFunctionTypes` flag is on.

Under this flag function type parameter positions are checked *contravariantly* instead of *bivariantly*.

This strange words should not bother you. I won't dive into the types theory (but I recommend you to read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/10118104)).

Let's say `B extends A`, `C extends B`, `D extends C` and so on. Then:

[image: Scheme]

In the question we have the problem assigning `B` to `A` cause its methods are not comparable. If `C extends B`, then if parameter positions are checked contravariantly `method(B)` is not comparable to `method(C)` (look at the image).

**Why do I need `strictFunctionTypes` in a first place?**

Let's look at the motivation example. First of all, disable the `strictFunctionTypes` flag.

```
interface Article {
  content: string;
}

interface TitledArticle extends Article {
  title: string;
}

let printer: (article: Article) => string;
```

Let's create the printer for the titled article:

```
let printer = (article: TitledArticle) => {
   return `${article.title.toUpperCase()} / ${article.content}`
}

printer({ content: "Great Answer" }); // exception
```

We've got exception, but TypeScript didn't warn us!

Well, it will warn if you enable `strictFunctionTypes`. That's the point.

*Once again: it's danger to assign the function `(arg: B) => void` to `(arg: A) => void`, because after such assignment you still will be able to pass `A` to this function and it can lead to different troubles, because `A` doesn't have all properties of `B`. That's why this rule is needed.*

**Why do I need check function type parameter positions bivariantly ever?**

Let's create the custom `CustomArray`:

```
class CustomArray<T> {
    // it's not method, it's a property and it's important!
    push = (item: T) => {
        // something
    }
}

let a = new CustomArray<number>();

let b = new CustomArray<0>();

a = b; // typescript error
```

```
Type 'CustomArray<0>' is not assignable to type 'CustomArray<number>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.
```

The same problem I assume occurred with default `Array`. That's why the Typescript developers leaves bivariantly checking of function type parameter position for constructors and methods, even if `strictFunctionTypes` is on.

> During development of this feature, we discovered a large number of inherently unsafe class hierarchies, including some in the DOM. Because of this, the setting only applies to functions written in function syntax, not to those in method syntax

You can check it himself, by replacing the property `push` by a method:

```
class CustomArray<T> {
    push(item: T) {
        // something
    }
}

let a = new CustomArray<number>();

let b = new CustomArray<0>();

a = b; // no error
```

So, you can rely on this peculiarity and use methods. But there are situations, where methods are just not good enough for you.

There are examples of the types where you can't use methods

```
interface A {
  method?: (a: this) => void;
}
```

```
interface A {
  method: ((a: this) => number) | number;
}
```

```
const callback = (e: Event) => void;
```

What can you do do in that situations?

**Bivariance hack**

There is the trick that can help you to force TypeScript check function type parameter positions bivariantly.

The idea is simple: if `strictFunctionTypes` doesn't applies to *methods*, let's make the function *a method*.

```
let callback: (event: E) => void
```

```
let callback: {'method': (event: E) => void}['method']
```

It's so easy but it works!

Let's write the generic type:

```
type Bivariant<T extends (...args: any) => any> = {
    f(...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>;
}['f'];
```

```
let callback: Bivariant<(event: E) => void>
```

It's still hack, but it's even nice now.

If you use it, don't worry. You are not alone. [React](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ec6e5981ab3c59704942f53f976cc0150f2feb39/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L84), [Material UI](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/9d6e08ba6883211828cdfcc44703ad7e2b131514/packages/mui-base/src/ModalUnstyled/ModalUnstyled.d.ts#L118) and many others use it. You are in the good company, just use it wisely, because with great power comes great responsibility (well, in a boring style, it reduces types safety).