# contravariance issue in typescript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types, interface, contravariance

Preemptive apologies if I'm abusing the term, but I'm able to implement an interface in typescript which I believe is not type safe, for example:

```js
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  dist (other: Point): number
}

GridPoint implements Point {
  constructor (public x: number, public x: number) {}
  dist (other: Point) { /* ... math here ... */ } //
}

NamedPoint implements Point {
  // this class has an extra `name: string` property...
  constructor (
    public x: number,
    public x: number,
    public name: string
  ) {}

  dist (other: NamedPoint) {
    // other is a NamedPoint so other.name is okay, but this
    // is not true of any Point, so how can NamedPoint be said
    // to implement point?
    if (other.name.startsWith()) { /* ... */ }
  }
}

// this will throw if `a` is a NamedPoint and `b` is a GridPoint
function getDist (a: Point, b: point) {
  console.log(`distance is: ${a.dist(b)}`)
}
// but tsc won't complain here:
getDist(new NamedPoint(1, 2, 'foo'), new GridPoint(9, 8));
```

[link to full example on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRgDwBUB8yA3gFDLnIAeAXMrgNxkUCetDT5A9J8gJLIB3dAFcANgBNkcAM7ThAWxRgAFnDDIVwaYJETkoAG5xRwcWpQA5OIvEYsU7cHkAHUREXhQAczSZwefA5kbmQAIwgEOGFpJWUUAAN0FWhaKxs7cHjkeTgAawhtNIhbPzAAOnEtdQR0cCg4IyhgOHBkAAp%20HOYgkPDkaO8NOI1oeX0QGqgoCLBRZgAaMOF1ZOQIGBgZ7Thp5HF3WukweshJcNF0AQBKHp4AMQB1XgfaeJqXYDcoAHlnMGBDmUjk0EGA7sIJv9arhmM4ClktMh4sdhBAESANNIaiAYMAvGUAFbSWqLATKYAIZS3PhDEReZTqIRiSRwZyuZjIOLTAD8QUqR3aSS5tAyOAIVzY1P4KjpDKGan60kGyPJ0iy8jxcvCqgMKEqG2gEHAcyW6mA6nE6AKIAA5OUymVqfz1G0hSkhloJXQSABfEgkBCiGTaADiTXEAGF0OgoJInK53EawNpRdgQApwlBCKQKFRaOn5JnGLnWMgC0WgtjgcJQTG2jQyxnoItS%20XoFdiEFc5ppGVKMgALxUYu5ig9socofMEfkP2552C5JQEWlNNNrNettQTujijTMDCKAYgCyamUZTgoWkbXH-YAtMg3VA%20x2ANTIU8qC9Xm%20qifIB8nwnK4Z2QOcx3QABlY5BjaL1gUGIhkH3Q8MXiABtAASIhbx9RZsPHZgfQAXXiegwN9f1A2DZAihKex4zcDxk18LA10LaBsyCBst1A1t11AkBrAgWgEJALxQKrFFayget83XFt5I4qBFiExRRJg8SOxzXcPV7fsh0oUDuz-SdkGnLsxz-NSUCHGygj9KUdGZNZKDhUE9I0dA9i0ABHYRjGAGAOTo0UHH0FwmKTQZRQAQj5KpF2FWjhPo8BN3XHddJCZxSm0Ml0BiMthOQI4dhYgRzWUIYUGkEq3DASBtx1FAAAYfLKiYIHi3T9BgJLoDKGygTAcrpAeKrfy0IbhKuDsUKPZBWuMigQifSqYkWZxmBUOAvBjCAWg60auss8gIFEIqFpPM8gV8qAwDaM7Rym-SAMfJcX2QAAqb7kAAJmQV9ntzV7-0Az7mA7X6AeekCHKCIIwCgzSfDgjSmnE4hkIgA9FowgjrOEn1aEJ6bKDw5Ayd7IjSPIv1HIDQ51C8BB2rsiABGQMNTCjGNxDaABGVrWsWQX-ta%20GpOQVnBcHMtOe58M%20djIXWoAVjFwX1fhpmQAFEBnHZhWudC0ohcWAAWRY7VqZgbSl5my2cOWOdN1LRTaABOK2bf%20ZGHcYEhWdaioqjaQ3JcYEJDcFsOjjaWWQOCHhPMRSJhHpMBFhkVz3NOeUQFyGAxDmB1HRIXpljT7QQCSeKS8hAEMWcTGwAAEXDuAVzYrd8EWUIe-8PuvQMTBJB06XJCHOB48e0J4fIKt0DcMoLi8Np4mdFokGQGAoHQMZsLgH0vKpogT-l7DxB9eJ4cc1usE7hPZcWEObkf8Bn8eyPVJd%20HP4d3DiHP%20UdK48EAd-COLs34IEFsnEIABRKYMZOSGloBCfYuIQDFBGmNCaKggA)

Again, I'm certain that I'm phrasing this the wrong way in terms of "contravariance" but I would think that `NamedPoint implements Point` would be forbidden by the compiler. I thought I could get this by turning on `strictFunctionTypes` in tsconfig, but that apparently doesn't apply to this situation.

Is it my understanding of types that is incorrect, or is typescript wrong here? If it's the latter, can I do anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of types is correct, but TypeScript is intentionally unsound when it comes to *method* parameters.  It treats methods as being [bivariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) in their parameter types.  As you saw, this is unsafe.  But it is convenient for TypeScript to do this, since otherwise there are certain built-in JavaScript class hierarchies which would no longer make type hierarchies.  It also allows people to [treat types like `Array<T>` as covariant in `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905518/why-are-typescript-arrays-covariant)... convenient, but unsafe.

This bivariance used to apply to all function types, but enabling the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) restricts this unsoundness to just method types.  Therefore, the fix in your case is to redefine `dist` from a method to a function-typed property:

```
interface Point<T> {
    x: T;
    y: T;
    dist: (other: Point<T>) => T // change
}
```

Nothing prevents you from *implementing* a function-typed property as a method, so your `GridCoord` class still compiles with no error.  But now `NamedPoint` gives you the expected error:

```
class NamedPoint implements Point<number> {

// ✂ snip ✂ //

    dist(other: NamedPoint): number { // error!
  //~~~~ <-- Type '(other: NamedPoint) => number' is not 
  //         assignable to type '(other: Point<number>) => number'.
        if (other.name.startsWith(this.name)) return 0;
        else return Math.sqrt(
            (this.x - other.x) ** 2 +
            (this.y - other.y) ** 2
        );
    }

}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRgDwBUB8yA3gFDLnIAeAXMrgNxkUCetDT5AJsAM5i0AKdGAAW0Whix58ASmQBeQrmQB6FcnQBrOMxIBfEiQQAbODx7IA4lGCcAwunRROyYAFsADsYhuI4C5Lg2CAArm4ARtCEpBRUtKER0IyxrMgJkVDJFAjoIHxQIQhgTgI0aWEZADTIqenQcjGxFKK8AHSUClRZTcgtPK3MnczdyAax3HxCouJomEF1ULLxFdDEqup8wMbGGtq6PeRQEGAhUCDIALJwoq1w4TwCfe3IALQa01DtcgDUl9cit3ujxEbUGb2EYk+zBkIzGzXQAGUwDYQABzAQyWj5UCotZHE5nZAAAwA2gASIhPSh6aoUp7MPQAXSJ9FG+kMJjMFgAcnBfJxAmBXJ5vL5-LMpAtohw4uVEpkZbUVgrYiA+RAscicSMcnlkYVilBSst5dUlaa0urNSjUQ0ZbEqZ1KCMHSD+oN5DUXc03a01b5Ov6IDKDDKJmAppDaLz+YLMXKMms1MhoFAnABCJhqAB+uezyGwLzeuGYHhQAHJIzMYxABXMwHJFAnoOXXBYQMJkFn1AdkFzgKi1eFvL10L1SxWq1AJPXgsrZApCAty617RRgDBkFO-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)