# TypeScript disallow unsafe casts of types with generic parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been learning TypeScript and I've encountered something strange. Take a look at this code:

```js
interface Foo {
    sayHello(): void;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    sayHello(): void {
        console.log("Bar Hello!");
    }

    sayGoodbye(): void {
        console.log("Bar Goodbye!");
    }
}

class Baz implements Foo {
    sayHello(): void {
        console.log("Baz Hello!");
    }
}

class TContainer<T extends Foo> {
    public value : T;

    constructor(value : T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

function run() {
    // barContainer.value should only ever be of type 'Bar'
    const barContainer : TContainer<Bar> = new TContainer(new Bar());

    // Cast barContainer and allow it to hold anything that implements Foo
    // (!!!) This should not be allowed
    const fooContainer : TContainer<Foo> = barContainer;
    
    // Set fooContainer.value (and thus barContainer.value) to a type without sayGoodbye
    fooContainer.value = new Baz();
    // Note that just writing barContainer.value = new Baz(); does correctly cause a compile time error.

    // Compiler still thinks barContainer.value is of type Bar, so this will crash at runtime
    barContainer.value.sayGoodbye();
}
```

TypeScript seems to allow casting generic types in an unsafe way which causes breakages at runtime. Other language's like C# or Java do not allow generic types to be converted like this, because it's unsafe.
**Is there any way to get the TypeScript compiler to report this as an error? If not, why not and how can I make types like `TContainer` safe?**

Comment: Have a read at this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: Which is the primary question here?  If it's your first question and the "why not", then the answer is "no" and I'd probably close this as a duplicate of [this question about array covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922930/2887218) which is the same issue: properties are related covariantly even though this is unsound in the face of mutation

Comment: If it's your second question then I'd suggest something like the code at [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE4KyW) to make the compiler treat `TContainer<T>` as invariant in `T`.  Does this fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; otherwise what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Well, I wasn't sure what was my primary question because I wasn't sure if there was an answer to the first one. That does look like a solution to the problem if you where to write up an answer :) I would appreciate some more elaboration on why it works, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general limitation of TypeScript; object types are compared *covariantly* in the types of their properties, meaning that if `Y extends X` then `{a: Y} extends {a: X}`.  (See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for an in-depth discussion of variance.)

For read-only properties that is safe, but in the face of property *assignment*, it's definitely unsound, as you've shown. But TypeScript is not intended to be fully sound, and [convenience often trumps soundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).  See [Why are TypeScript arrays covariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60905518/2887218) for a more in-depth discussion.

So `TContainer<T>` is covariant in `T` because the only dependence on `T` is that there is a `value` property of type `T`.  One workaround would therefore be to add a *contravariant* dependency, so that `TContainer<T>` is considered to be *invariant* in `T`.  As long as you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled, then if `TContainer<T>` has a function-valued property that accepts an argument of type `T`, then it will have this effect:

```
class TContainer<T extends Foo> {
    public value: T;
    private invariant = (x: T) => x; // add this or something like it
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now you get the desired error:

```
const barContainer: TContainer<Bar> = new TContainer(new Bar());
const fooContainer: TContainer<Foo> = barContainer; // error!
```

---

Note that it will *not* work if you make `invariant` a *method* instead of a function-valued property:

```
class TContainer<T extends Foo> {
    public value: T;
    private bivariant(x: T) { return x }; // <-- nope
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
const barContainer: TContainer<Bar> = new TContainer(new Bar());
const fooContainer: TContainer<Foo> = barContainer; // no error
```

since method parameters are compared *bivariantly*... this is, again, unsound, but convenient.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=26&pc=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyAznAJ4ASEANjegBQCUAXMgG7rAAmA3AQF8CBBDTgkSyAEJwoyYAFsADjQgKI4SRix5CxMlVr1mbTjxwFiV5AnQgS6VQDp6AcwYAiGXOp10AQg8mfj0iIXxLfQoAcUxuACNyCBMOLm4LUOtbe0cIF3R3L1lkWPQEpMDgyLDBYXxRcUkZAC95ZVV1TTRMDKsDX2NWVPNda2Jsh2c3TxbkAYCgkKtw8JExCWQAFQBhOzA4UGgAHk3kCAAPSBBuLUwAPl7iJQBXeJpgBA44GmeINk2lk8oMB2HBIPIQKDgXBwMgALzIBjnf5MeEPc68ZAAeixyDg3HSYAAFsASNUbHYSGAoM8EGB0FAGKCfn8tqjRmNkMTSU5mb94V8WYCavhVvgYM8QHTgHZkDSQMxHkQJmBkPFZLtwAcQNB-pr9ocoEdvA8ETqAO5bfXa6AMC3SWTMKqZFXIGCYa2GvV7G1G7SmtUan2GzE4s5QKAM-zk93oT06qC8778s0QS0tZjCwNQePQJMspwGUrlZLOsUgODqEhKRAoABy6CUKF05IaGx2wYTJzOlw0N266AeHLGLzeH0Fv3+WasSmBoPB8RBsmAMLASJRODlEDAzygIGQ52QAmn40p1Np9MZfNZm3Z5M5XJJJHzKYnEBPIuWdSsEqlYBl+7yoqw5ZGe2a5lA3paoaxqyAG9odtBCZ2mmDqMkwzoPq6sYQVBBpdv6ArqjmnbQKGuIgFg0CRlA97EDhpGJteAr2hmmGcsREEvnkRZxIkpZZisQA)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, it's a shame there is no way to tell the compiler to make the T generic variable invariant without this kinda 'hacky' solution. I probably wont end up using it just because it would probably be pretty confusing to anybody reading the code who isn't 'in the know'. Thanks for furthering my understanding, though