# Generic function to convert enum to array that also accepts null values

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to create a generic function in TypeScript to convert an enum to an array that also accepts `null` values?

Something like this:

```
enum Color
{
    RED   = "Red",
    GREEN = "Green",
    BLUE  = "Blue"
}

let colors = convertEnumToArray(Color);
colors.push(null);
```

Where `colors` is of type `(Color | null)[]`.

I've found the function below in this link and I'd like to modify it to allow `null` in the array:

https://blog.oyam.dev/typescript-enum-values/

```
type EnumObject = {[key: string]: number | string};
type EnumObjectEnum<E extends EnumObject> = E extends {[key: string]: infer ET | string} ? ET : never;

function convertEnumToArray<E extends EnumObject>(enumObject: E): Array<EnumObjectEnum<E> | null> {
    const elements = Object.values(enumObject)
        .filter(key => Number.isNaN(Number(key)))
        .map(key => enumObject[key] as (EnumObjectEnum<E> | null));
    elements.unshift(null);
    return elements;
}
```

But I think there should be an easier way, or am I wrong?

Comment: Just write `let colors: (Color | null)[] = convertEnumToArray(Color);`, even if the return type of `convertEnumToArray(Color)` is `Color[]`

Comment: I would like that type returned from the function itself, not in the call site (which was, by the way, my first "solution").

Comment: If you're happy with the function from that blog, all you need to do is annotate the return type's array element type with `| null`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQgrW).  That's the "easiest" way, given that function.  But that function acts weird given a mixed numeric/string enum.  If you want to write it yourself, you could do it like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn826W). Which of those solutions would you like to see posted as an answer, if any?

Comment: The function is ok to me as I don't mix types in enums. It seems that the function is already simple enough for the job and can't be made easier. First solution is better.

Comment: Then could you please [edit] the question to specifically say: "I have this function and I'd like to modify it to allow `null` in the array?" That way the answer doesn't have to delve into the general "how to create this function" question, which would almost certainly involve concerns not addressed by the function from that blog, especially for future readers who may have slightly different use cases that match the current question wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) in TypeScript are considered to be *covariant* in their element types (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) and [Why are TypeScript arrays covariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60905518/2887218)).  So that means that if you have an `Array<X>` for some type `X`, then you can use it directly as an `Array<X | null>`, since the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `X | null` is wider than `X`.  So if you've got a function that returns `X[]` and you'd like it to return `(X | null)[]`, *all you need to do* is [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) as `(X | null)[]`.  The compiler will accept it.

So starting with the function from that blog, which we assume meets your needs except for the `null` element part:

```
function getEnumValues<E extends EnumObject>(
    enumObject: E
): EnumObjectEnum<E>[] {
    return Object.keys(enumObject)
        .filter(key => Number.isNaN(Number(key)))
        .map(key => enumObject[key] as EnumObjectEnum<E>);
}
```

the only change necessary is in the annotated return type:

```
function getEnumValues<E extends EnumObject>(
    enumObject: E
): (EnumObjectEnum<E> | null)[] { // <-- change here
    return Object.keys(enumObject)
        .filter(key => Number.isNaN(Number(key)))
        .map(key => enumObject[key] as EnumObjectEnum<E>);
}
```

And then your code will work as desired:

```
enum Color {
    RED = "Red",
    GREEN = "Green",
    BLUE = "Blue"
}

let colors = getEnumValues(Color);
// let colors: (Color | null)[]
colors.push(null); // okay
```

That's it.

Again, for any future readers, it is just assumed that the original function works as desired; in practice, that definition might do weird things if you have mixed numeric/string enums.  The point of this answer is merely to show how you can just add `| null` to the right place in a return type annotation, and not to endorse any particular function for converting an enum to an array of its values.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAUQHYFcC2B5ARgKxgYzDgF44BvOAbQGsYIAuOAZzACcBLJAcwF1HU0WGKzgAfZm05c4AXwDcoSLEQDseQsnQAeBHBgAPMDCQATJivRqCYAHwlEew8bPkqtBhI7c+cTgDNhRAAVMU8pWTgAfmC4fhgAN2EFEFA-FCRCdgB7JDguGDBNNAA1AEMAGxQYJh1HI1NzIqtCGwAKY0tca0YEAEpGVqaujQEdO3FUcvLeyh5yUDhFuAB6ZaX1jc2t7Z3dvb2APSPjg7gtAFpzuDAAC1KwAHJzCvK4CCyUOCQYGBNrrLgJiyCyWrAKKFYuWaYAAdO4mO1VMMwL0QZsYX52OUjKxWu4SHYAHLoISsGHsJiE0qE1rEwTCPF0XrMtEbGFoUpQRkQAl6JHqMA0OhzUqNfnWIpjXrJGSgOUgDpoOAAYSy5SyIjIrIASggACL2ABE2t+hoANKyAOK6hCEo2WsHGc2sgBCABkAKq6UiGl2VGCG0CylIgcoFOD4NUa8ykfKFARlf0I1Xq1jS0CrOBhoiR1NMAYpjWhSbTWagXPRmFQFBMG6tEvSlZrLLUUoQIA)