Different generic type overlap of lamba field and its class
Consider this example (live example):
interface Foo<T>
{
    readonly fun: (v: T) => void; // causes error below
    //fun(v: T): void; // works
}

function isNumber<T>(foo: Foo<T>): foo is Foo<T & number>
{
    return true;
} 

this produces the error 2677:
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'Foo<T & number>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<T>'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T & number'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2677)

But the problem goes away if we replace readonly fun: (v: T) => void; with a member function fun(v: T): void;. Why is this a problem, and is there a way to still use a lambda field here?
Our suspicion is that foo is a (dynamic) field and its type can change later with an overwrite, therefore the T of the lambdas parameter is not the same T as in the Foo<T & number> context. And since a member function assumably has more tight type restrictions it receives the correct T & number type.

Functions are contravariant in their parameters (with --strictFunctionTypes, which explains why). Every function of type (x: T)=>void is already a function of type (x: T & number)=>void (if f accepts a T then it obviously accepts something which is both a T and a number), so you don't have to narrow it. It's a widening, not a narrowing; you can just return it. What are you trying to actually accomplish here? Please [edit] to clarify in light of this info.

@jcalz your comment made us realize that due to the type widening our typing needs to be changed. A more appropriate solution for us is defining all interfaces and creating a discriminated union out of the interfaces.

live example

I'm confused about what to do here now, and I'm afraid I don't quite understand the example (note that T extends number mostly just means you're looking at numeric literal types? Or is it just supposed to be number here?... and what's the [T] vs [T, T] distinction doing? A pair vs a singleton?). Could you please [edit] the question itself to make it clear what you're asking and then we can answer it? Or is it that the question has some false premise and should just be removed instead of answered?

first of all, thank you for explaining the behaviour in great detail. My question was why the lambda field fails but the member function works, you're statement that functions are contravariant answers the question, so you are welcome to create an answer and I will mark it as accepted. I simply noted that the widening vs narrowing note made us realize that our attempt needed to be reworked, but explaining each detail here goes beyond the scope of this minimal reproducible example, sorry for causing potential confusions here.

When the --strictFunctionTypes compiler flag is enabled, functions are contravariant in their parameters (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript).  That means if T extends U then ((x: U) => void) extends ((x: T) => void), not vice versa. Notice the change of direction.  This makes sense if you try to imagine that function parameters are themselves a change in the direction of data flow from how you normally think of types. You're talking about data being accepted, not produced. Dogs are animals, and cats are animals. But if I bring my dog to an "animal doctor" that refuses to help because she only works on cats, the fact that "cats are animals" doesn't make the situation any more palatable. A true animal doctor accepts all animals. Every animal doctor is also a cat doctor, but not every cat doctor is an animal doctor.
Anyway, your Foo<T> type is contravariant in T.  And thus there is no reason for you to try to narrow a Foo<T> to a Foo<T & number>.  Every Foo<T> is automatically a Foo<T & number>, in the same way that every animal doctor is automatically a cat doctor:
function toNumber<T>(foo: Foo<T>): Foo<T & number> {
    return foo; // okay
} 

Moving from Foo<T> to Foo<T & number> is a widening, not a narrowing. And if you try to make a user defined type guard function that actually widens, TypeScript complains that you're doing it wrong:
function isString(x: "a" | "b"): x is string { // error!
//                               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    return true;
}

You can't "narrow" "a" | "b" to string, and you can't "narrow" Foo<T> to Foo<T & number>.

So that's why it's happening. If you switch from function types like {a: (x: T) => void} to method types like {a(x: T): void}, TypeScript uses bivariance to measure the parameters, and your errors go away. Bivariance is unsafe, but sometimes useful (see [https://stackoverflow.com/q/60905518/2887218] for example). But unless you're willingly writing unsafe code, I'd say you should step back and figure out what you're really doing and maybe refactor.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked.
Playground link to code
