# Any generic in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Nowadays I am learning Kotlin and I have a question. I'm writing the code below and I get the error "The integer literal does not conform to the expected type String".

```
fun main() {

fun <Any> MutableList<Any>.yaz(name : Any) : Any = name;

var mutableList : MutableList<String> = ArrayList<String>()

println(mutableList.yaz(1))
println(mutableList.yaz("Selam"))

}
```

Where am I making a mistake? I would be very happy if you can help. Thanks!

It works when I write as follows, but I didn't understand why.

```
fun <Any> MutableList<out Any>.yaz(name : Any) : Any = name;
```

Comment: Are you intending `Any` to mean the usual type `kotlin.Any`?  Because it's not: by specifying `<Any>` it's simply the name of the type parameter within the definition of `yaz()`.  (That's why we usually use single letters for type parameters, to avoid this sort of confusion.)

Comment: What's the difference between <Any> and <out Any> ? @gidds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gidds said in the comments, you might be writing `Any` to mean the `Any` type in Kotlin, however as you have specified `Any` as a generic of the function `yaz`, then it no longer represents a reified type.

Explicitly,

```
fun <Any> MutableList<Any>.yaz(name : Any) : Any = name;
```

is equivalent to

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.yaz(name : T) : T = name;
```

So therefore the reason that your example doesn't compile is because you are specifying that the type of `MutableList` should be the same as the type of the `name` parameter, which is not true when using a `MutableList<String>` and `name = 1`.

---

The `out` parameter in Koltin declares something as a producer, but there is a very detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65648074/10082297) that will explain it better than I can. However the fact that your example with `out` works fine is a mystery to me, so it would be nice to have someone clear that up.

Comment: Great! I still don't know why adding `out` allows it to compile, so if you ever find out, let me know!