# Why "out T" for constructor input?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I found the following code in the Kotlin [forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/union-types/77/126) and it works [fine](https://pl.kotl.in/j1jTqZbYs).

```kotlin
sealed class JsonValue<out T>(val value: T) {
    class JsonString(value: String) : JsonValue<String>(value)
    class JsonBoolean(value: Boolean) : JsonValue<Boolean>(value)
    class JsonNumber(value: Number) : JsonValue<Number>(value)
    object JsonNull : JsonValue<Nothing?>(null)
    class JsonArray<V>(value: Array<V>) : JsonValue<Array<V>>(value)
    class JsonObject(value: Map<String, Any?>) : JsonValue<Map<String, Any?>>(value)

    override fun toString(): String = value.toString()
}

fun main() {
    var pi: JsonValue<Any?>
    pi = JsonValue.JsonString("pi"); println (pi)
    pi = JsonValue.JsonNumber(3.14); println (pi)
    pi = JsonValue.JsonNull; println (pi)
}
```

But I do not understand why it uses `out T`.

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65648074/402322) to a question about `out` in general states:

> `out T` [...] means functions can return `T` but they can't take `T` as arguments.
>
> `in T` [...] means functions can take `T` as arguments but they can't return `T`.

If I take a look at the above code, I can see many constructors (functions), which take `T` (the `value`) as an argument. And I see no function which returns `T`. So my inital impression was: this must be a typo, it should be `in T`. But it does not even compile with `in T`.

Why is it necessary to use `out T`, although the type goes *into* the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor doesn't really *count* :) Only *instance* members matter - things that you can do to *instances* of `JsonValue`.

As explained in the linked answer, the whole idea of (declaration-site) covariance is that you are allowed to implicitly convert an *instance* of e.g. `JsonValue<String>` to `JsonValue<Any?>` if the type `JsonValue<T>` satisfies some requirements. One of the requirements is that `JsonValue<T>` should not have any functions that take in any `T`s<sup>*</sup>, because if it did, weird things like this would happen:

```
val x: JsonValue<Any?> = JsonString("foo")
x.giveMeSomeT(123)
```

`x` at runtime holds an instance of `JsonString`, but the `giveMeSomeT` method in `JsonString` would expect a `String`, not an `Int`, but as far as the compiler is concerned, `x` is a `JsonValue<Any?>`, so this should compile, and bad things would happen at runtime.

So this is why having a function that takes in `T`s stops you from marking `JsonValue` as `out T`. However, having a constructor that takes in a `T` is not problematic at all, since situations like the above cannot happen with just a constructor.

> And I see no function which returns `T`

In fact, the getter of `value` returns `T`. Also note that you do not *need* something that returns `T` to in order to say `out T`. You just need to to have nothing that takes in `T`s. This is vacuously valid for example:

```
class Foo<out T>
```

---

<sup>*</sup> More accurately and generally, whenever I say "take in any `T`s", it should be "have `T` in an 'in' position", and whenever I say "return a `T`", it should be "have `T` in an 'out' position". This is to account for `T`s being used as the type argument of other generic types.